# How to make a factorial program in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, factorial

I am new to this website; in fact this is my first question. So if I am asking this question in the wrong context, please inform me so I can make the adjustments.
I have a program that is created in Visual Studio 2010 to allow a user to enter in an integer from 1 to 10. That user will click a button which in turn should compute and display the integer's factorial value in a text box. I thought everything looks correct but nothing is appearing in the text box.

The following code is what I have been using:

```
#pragma endregion
        private: System::Void btnFactorial_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
        {
            int n;
            int nfact = 1;
            Int32::TryParse(txtNum->Text, n);
            if (n > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                    nfact *= i;
                txtResult->Text = nfact.ToString();
            }
            else
                MessageBox::Show ("Please enter a value > 0");      
        }

        private: int Factorial (int n)
        {
            if (n == 0)
                return 1;
            else
                return n * Factorial (n-1);
        }
    };
}
```

Can I ask for some help as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't seem to call Factorial anywhere. Not from btnFactorial anyway.

Comment: step through using the debugger. F10 steps over to next line...

Comment: Thanks I will try that now. I receive no errors or warnings and the form loads correctly to allow the user to enter in the integer value but nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: It's a trifle for what you are doing perhaps, but 0! is valid.

Comment: doesn't this code: txtResult->Text = nfact.ToString(); call the value to the text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your own function somewhere. Replace this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                nfact *= i;
```

and write this:

```
nfact = Factorial(n);
```

Comment: I tried doing this and I get the same result; nothing appearing in the text box that should show the factorial value of the integer that is entered into the first text box by the user.

Comment: Yes which is showing me no errors. Unless there is another way to debug and I'm not doing it right. I am extremely new to using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I am sorry, there are a lot of things that can be wrong somewhere else. As a last try, replace int n; for Int32 n; and int nfact; for Int32 nfact;

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason the btnFactorial_Click_1 object wasn't working right. So I double click it again to re-engage it, copied the existing code, deleted to old click object and it works. Thanks everyone.